# My video loads inside my svg, but when i host it on live server the video doesn't load. Statically it works

Tags: javascript, html, svg, video, mp4

So i embedded a video inside my svg, and it worked. But when i load it and set it as a background-image. The svg loads. But the video inside it buffers but doesn't actually load. It is supposed to auto play the video. As shown below.

https://codepen.io/audiophones_/pen/WNgWVPr

I'm assuming this has to do with live server and serving files. Is there a way to get my video to load inside my svg? Not sure what it didn't load correctly.

This is the code snippet where i use the video tag inside a foreign object in my svg. The codepen shows a full version of this.

```
 <g clip-path="url(#myClipPath)">
                                  
          <foreignObject   width="927.74" height="595.39" x="290" y="110">
  <video  id="myvide" type="video/mp4" preload="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="927.74" height="595.39" autoplay="true" loop="1" muted="true">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
</foreignObject>

                                  
                                   <!-- <foreignObject  width="400" height="200" x="490" y="210">

    <video xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  width="400" height="200" xhtml="video"
    allow="autoplay"  preload="" autoplay="autoplay" loop="1" muted="muted" controls="" playinline="true" >
         <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </foreignObject> -->
  <!--  x and y is the positioning    -->
                                  </g>
```

Comment: _"I'm assuming this has to do with live server and serving files."_ - doubt it; I think much more likely it has to do with this: _"and set it as a background-image"_ - what SVG images are "allowed" to do, differs massively depending on whether the SVG is actually part of the HTML - or embedded as an external resource (using img, object, or - as a background image.) The latter doesn't allow for any sort of inline scripting, for example - and I can image that it is probably the same for foreignObject and similar content.

Comment: is the video source the same?

Comment: @Apodemus It is, i set the src attribute as  https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4 in the source tag. I've also set the src tag in the video tag  to be the same https sourced mp4. yet i still get a grey video screen when i host it as a live server.

Comment: Interesting @CBroe thanks for your insight, so i have to set it as part of the html, instead of setting it as a background image of a class associated with my body tag. Trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: i got it to work kind of. proof of concept is there. the inline css idea really helped. the problem is it kinda interferes with my other videos, probably need to set it by id. i set the entire svg as a inner text inside my html. enabled by javascript in order to pull it off. when i have a final product i'll paste it here for future use.